# GAE doesn't serve up html on localhost

Tags: python, google-app-engine

just begun working through the book "Code in the Cloud" which is an introduction to GAE. I've followed most of the examples in the book with mixed results; I'm beginning to feel the book is a bit dated. One of the exercises is to make a simple chat room.

I have been debugging the code for longer than I'd like to admit and my frustration has reached its end. When I navigate to the localhost server, nothing is served. No HTML, no error, nothing.

The code is as follows:
main.py - http://pastebin.com/hnkWvvX6
app.yaml - http://pastebin.com/7y51tgGR

If anyone could give me any insight whatsoever as to where I'm going wrong, I'd be extremely appreciative!

Regards,
Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that should have given you a NameError in the console when you ran the server. Your app.yaml is pointing all URLs to "main.app", but your main.py does not expose anything called "app", it only exposes "chatapp" - that's defined in line 57. You should change one or other of them so that they match.

Note that everything after that block - the `main()` function and the `if` block underneath it - are completely unnecessary and should be removed, although they have no effect on your current issue.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Changed that one declaration and everything worked! I was unaware the .app was a reference to a resource inside the code.